# Why won't my Amazon links open? using bootstrap modal python

Tags: python, html, bootstrap-modal

I edited this code originally from youtube links. It used to have a small window screen that pops up with video trailers from youtube. Right now the code just pops up a small blank window screen. How can I get the new amazon links to open up? Thank you!

```
import webbrowser
import os
import re

# Styles and scripting for the page
main_page_head = '''
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gold Pineapples!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding-top: 80px;
        }
        #link .modal-dialog {
            margin-top: 200px;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
        }
        .hanging-close {
            position: absolute;
            top: -12px;
            right: -12px;
            z-index: 9001;
        }
        #link-popup {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .item-name {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .item-name:hover {
            background-color: #EEE;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .scale-media {
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .scale-media iframe {
            border: none;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Pause the popup when the modal is closed
        $(document).on('click', '.hanging-close, .modal-backdrop, .modal', function (event) {
            // Remove the src so the player itself gets removed, as this is the only
            // reliable way to ensure the popup stops playing in IE
            $("#link-popup-container").empty();
        });
        // Start playing the popup whenever the link modal is opened
        $(document).on('click', '.item-name', function (event) {
            var linkAmazonId = $(this).attr('data-link-amazon-id')
            var sourceUrl = 'http://www.amazon.com/embed/' + linkAmazonId + '?autoplay=1&html5=1';
            $("#link-popup-container").empty().append($("<iframe></iframe>", {
              'id': 'link-popup',
              'type': 'text-html',
              'src': sourceUrl,
              'frameborder': 0
            }));
        });
        // Animate in the items when the page loads
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.item-name').hide().first().show("fast", function showNext() {
            $(this).next("div").show("fast", showNext);
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
'''

# The main page layout and title bar
main_page_content = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!-- Link Popup Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="link">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <a href="#" class="hanging-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/v4-628SilF0HtHuHdu5EzxD7WRqOrrTIDi_MhEG6_qkNtUK5Wg7KPkofp_VJoF7RS2LhxwEFCO1ICHZlc-o_=s0#w=24&h=24"/>
          </a>
          <div class="scale-media" id="link-popup-container">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Suggested Items: </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {item_tiles}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

# A single item entry html template
item_tile_content = '''
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 item-name text-center" data-link-amazon-id="{link_amazon_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#link">
    <img src="{item_image_url}" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>{item_name}</h2>
</div>
'''

def create_item_names_content(items):
    # The HTML content for this section of the page
    content = ''
    for item in items:
        # Extract the youtube ID from the url
        amazon_id_match = re.search(r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', item.link_amazon_url)
        amazon_id_match = amazon_id_match or re.search(r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', item.link_amazon_url)
        link_amazon_id = amazon_id_match.group(0) if amazon_id_match else None

        # Append the namefor the item with its content filled in
        content += item_tile_content.format(
            item_name=item.name,
            item_image_url=item.item_image_url,
            link_amazon_id=link_amazon_id
        )
    return content

def open_items_page(items):
  # Create or overwrite the output file
  output_file = open('gold_pineapples.html', 'w')

  # Replace the placeholder for the item names with the actual dynamically generated content
  rendered_content = main_page_content.format(item_tiles=create_item_names_content(items))

  # Output the file
  output_file.write(main_page_head + rendered_content)
  output_file.close()

  # open the output file in the browser
  url = os.path.abspath(output_file.name)
  webbrowser.open('file://' + url, new=2) # open in a new tab, if possible
```

Here is my code I originally started with:

```
import webbrowser
import os
import re

# Styles and scripting for the page
main_page_head = '''
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fresh Tomatoes!</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap 3 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            padding-top: 80px;
        }
        #trailer .modal-dialog {
            margin-top: 200px;
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
        }
        .hanging-close {
            position: absolute;
            top: -12px;
            right: -12px;
            z-index: 9001;
        }
        #trailer-video {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .movie-tile {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        .movie-tile:hover {
            background-color: #EEE;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .scale-media {
            padding-bottom: 56.25%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .scale-media iframe {
            border: none;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Pause the video when the modal is closed
        $(document).on('click', '.hanging-close, .modal-backdrop, .modal', function (event) {
            // Remove the src so the player itself gets removed, as this is the only
            // reliable way to ensure the video stops playing in IE
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty();
        });
        // Start playing the video whenever the trailer modal is opened
        $(document).on('click', '.movie-tile', function (event) {
            var trailerYouTubeId = $(this).attr('data-trailer-youtube-id')
            var sourceUrl = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + trailerYouTubeId + '?autoplay=1&html5=1';
            $("#trailer-video-container").empty().append($("<iframe></iframe>", {
              'id': 'trailer-video',
              'type': 'text-html',
              'src': sourceUrl,
              'frameborder': 0
            }));
        });
        // Animate in the movies when the page loads
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.movie-tile').hide().first().show("fast", function showNext() {
            $(this).next("div").show("fast", showNext);
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>
'''

# The main page layout and title bar
main_page_content = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <!-- Trailer Video Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="trailer">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <a href="#" class="hanging-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            <img src="https://lh5.ggpht.com/v4-628SilF0HtHuHdu5EzxD7WRqOrrTIDi_MhEG6_qkNtUK5Wg7KPkofp_VJoF7RS2LhxwEFCO1ICHZlc-o_=s0#w=24&h=24"/>
          </a>
          <div class="scale-media" id="trailer-video-container">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Main Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Stephanie's Suggested Movie Trailers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      {movie_tiles}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''

# A single movie entry html template
movie_tile_content = '''
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 movie-tile text-center" data-trailer-youtube-id="{trailer_youtube_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trailer">
    <img src="{poster_image_url}" width="220" height="342">
    <h2>{movie_title}</h2>
</div>
'''

def create_movie_tiles_content(movies):
    # The HTML content for this section of the page
    content = ''
    for movie in movies:
        # Extract the youtube ID from the url
        youtube_id_match = re.search(r'(?<=v=)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        youtube_id_match = youtube_id_match or re.search(r'(?<=be/)[^&#]+', movie.trailer_youtube_url)
        trailer_youtube_id = youtube_id_match.group(0) if youtube_id_match else None

        # Append the tile for the movie with its content filled in
        content += movie_tile_content.format(
            movie_title=movie.title,
            poster_image_url=movie.poster_image_url,
            trailer_youtube_id=trailer_youtube_id
        )
    return content

def open_movies_page(movies):
  # Create or overwrite the output file
  output_file = open('fresh_tomatoes.html', 'w')

  # Replace the placeholder for the movie tiles with the actual dynamically generated content
  rendered_content = main_page_content.format(movie_tiles=create_movie_tiles_content(movies))

  # Output the file
  output_file.write(main_page_head + rendered_content)
  output_file.close()

  # open the output file in the browser
  url = os.path.abspath(output_file.name)
  webbrowser.open('file://' + url, new=2) # open in a new tab, if possible
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://the-website-address.com" target="_blank">This will open in another tab</a>
```